# Multivariable Calculus: Gini Index?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> The following integral is called the Gini energy: E = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x-y|f(x)f(y)dxdy$.
>   The Gini index $\frac{E}{m}$ , where $m = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx $
>    is the mean, and it plays a role in computing wealth inequality.
>   Find the Gini index for f(x) = 1 on [0, 1] and f(x) = 0 else.

Frankly, I don't understand how to begin. We're given f(x) = 1, so we know that the mean is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx $, which is just some constant. Can someone walk me through this one?

Comment: You're not given $f(x)=1$, you're given $f(x) = 1$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1$.  So $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-y|f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 |x-y|\,dx$.

Comment: And then for the iterated integral, it would just be $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} |x-y|dxdy$?

Comment: Still confused about how to solve the integral you gave... two functioned integral with one integrand?

Comment: Are you familiar with iterated integrals? The inside integral, once x is integrated out, remains a function of y. So integrate that function with respect to y. You may be able to use symmetry to simplify first.

Comment: But is my double integral, posted above in this comment thread, correct?

Comment: Yes, and notice that symmetry means that you can write it as $2\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^x (x-y) \, dy \right) dx$.

Comment: Still don't understand how to solve the problem... can anyone help??

Comment: I think I know why you didn't know where to begin.  Read up on iterated integrals before trying to go forward with this problem.

Comment: No, I understand how to solve iterated integrals. My confused, though, is with *m*. How do I solve for this function? Is it just xdx?

Comment: $m$ isn't a function.  It's a number.  $m = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 1\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, we have learned that
\begin{align*}
    E &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x-y|\,dy \,dx 
       = 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^x (x-y)\,dy\,dx \\
      &= 2 \int_0^1 \left[xy-\frac{y^2}{2}\right]^{y=x}_{y=0}\,dx \\
      &= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{2}\,dx = \int_0^1 x^2\,dx = \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
And
$$
    m = \int_0^1 1\,dx = 1
$$
So, $G = \frac{1}{3}$.